Arkscan 2054A Direct Thermal Printer doesn’t work correctly
I have tried to get my printer to work with no luck.
I found a driver for it on arkscan website and instruction.
Download the driver installer, grant the downloaded file executable by the following command 'chmod 777 Arkscan_2054A_Linux_Driver' (without single quotes) on a terminal, and then run Arkscan_2054A_Linux_Driver
I did it. It printed one page. After a while settings are the same but printer prints in different scale.
When I sent to the printer 2 pages, it printed the first and the second one two pages together. One page on to another.
I removed printer.
Installed a driver from database. It is 4barcode printer.
Printer did the same things.
What would you recommend to do ?

You've not provided Ubuntu product & release details; so we're somewhat limited in what we can provide.

Access the CUPS (Common Unix Printing System)  GUI at http://localhost:631 Add/configure your printer from the Admin tab.
